# Should i use IIF and ISNULL to select a default-value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is this the best way to select default value from the table if selecting value is `0` or `null`?

```
DECLARE @value INT = 15 
DECLARE @defaultValue INT = 12

SELECT IIF(ISNULL(@value,0) = 0, @defaultValue, @value)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify "best". Since `IIF` works only in SQL-Server i'd use `CASE` which is ANSI SQL standard and works in every(?) rdbms:

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN ISNULL(@value,0) = 0 THEN  @defaultValue ELSE @value END
```

Actually [`IIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) is even translated to `CASE`:

> IIF is a shorthand way for writing a CASE expression ...
>   The fact that IIF is translated into CASE also has an impact on other
>   aspects of the behavior of this function....

But the same is true for `ISNULL` which is also a `SQL-Server` function and could be replaced by `COALECSE`.

By the way,  if you use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` in a `WHERE`-clause, it  prevents the query optimizer from using an index. So then you should prefer:

```
SELECT  ...
FROM dbo.TableName
WHERE @value IS NOT NULL AND @value <> @value
```

However, i prefer `ISNULL` over `COALESCE` since the latter has an issue if it contains a sub-query. It is executed twice whereas `ISNULL` executes it once. Actually `COALESCE` is also translated into `CASE`. You can read about that issue [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/546437/coalesce-subquery-1-may-return-null).

Comment: But `ISNULL()` is also SQL Server-specific.

Comment: @DavidFaber: i've already edited my answer. However, i prefer `ISNULL` over `COALESCE` since the latter has an issue if it contains a sub-query. It is executed twice whereas `ISNULL` executes it once. Actually `COALESCE` is also translated into CASE. https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/546437/coalesce-subquery-1-may-return-null

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [COALESCE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx). It evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to `NULL`. It is used for this purpose to get the first `not null` value.

```
 SELECT COALESCE(@value,@defaultValue)
```

But keep in mind,

> If all arguments are NULL, COALESCE returns NULL. At least one of the
>   null values must be a typed NULL.

You can also use the `ISNULL` but there is difference between both of them that is as listed below,

**Comparing COALESCE and ISNULL**

> 1) The `ISNULL` function and the `COALESCE` expression have a similar
>   purpose but can behave differently. Because `ISNULL` is a function, it
>   is evaluated only once. As described above, the input values for the
>   `COALESCE` expression can be evaluated multiple times.
>   2) Data type
>   determination of the resulting expression is different. `ISNULL` uses
>   the data type of the first parameter, `COALESCE` follows the `CASE`
>   expression rules and returns the data type of value with the highest
>   precedence.
>   3) The `NULLability` of the result expression is
>   different for `ISNULL` and `COALESCE`. The `ISNULL` return value is
>   always considered `NOT NULLable (assuming the return value is a non-nullable one)` whereas `COALESCE` with non-null parameters is
>   considered to be `NULL`. So the expressions `ISNULL(NULL, 1)` and
>   `COALESCE(NULL, 1)` although equivalent have different `nullability`
>   values. This makes a difference if you are using these expressions in
>   computed columns, creating key constraints or making the return value
>   of a scalar UDF deterministic so that it can be indexed as shown in
>   the following example.

If you are planning to use the sub queries in the expression to  check for the `NULL` then you better of using the `ISNULL` as `COALESCE` will evaluate same query multiple times.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `COALESCE` is translated into `CASE`.

Comment: @k29 The Op was asking subjective questions regarding the best approach nowhere in an answer did I mention that any approach would be better, for his current question as the question does not contain all the information. Also if you read carefully answer is subjective and suggest the use of one of them as per his requirement.  And looking at the comments you have on all the answers it seems you want an objective answer. On SO there are different approaches and answers are suggested it's up to OP to select the best working solution for him. Also, your comment is 5 years late in a sense.

Answer (score -1):

It can be a lot of arguments what is the best way and what it not, but
for me it is slightly more readable when using `case` syntax:

```
select case when @value is null then @defaultValue else @value end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `CASE` statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @value IS NULL THEN @defaultValue ELSE @value END
```

---

Or `COALESCE` expression

```
SELECT COALESCE(@value,@defaultValue)
```